# ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory: HyperV Docker

Tags: python, hyper-v

I am very new to this and trying to learn Docker/Containers. I have created a user form using pyqt5 and now trying to containerize that using hyper v docker. Everything goes well until the image creation. However when I am trying to run the container, I came across the below error. Tried many an things but did not work. can some of you advise the best solution for this:

Dockerfile:

FROM python
RUN python -m pip install PyQT5
RUN python -m pip install pyqt5-tools
COPY Test.py c:/python_practice/DTM/
CMD python c:/python_practice/DTM/Test.py

Error code:

PS C:\Python_Practice\DTM> docker run pydocker
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/python_practice/DTM/Test.py", line 1, in 
    from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please note sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx is not working as this is windows not linux.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following lines to your docker file:

`RUN apt-get update -y`

`RUN apt install libgl1-mesa-glx -y`