# ImportError: libgssapi_krb5.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-venv

I have been getting the following error when trying to run one one of my Python Programs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Path/to/program/Main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from src.ui.python import Home
  File "/Path/to/program/src/ui/python/Home.py", line 13, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
ImportError: libgssapi_krb5.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am currently using a python virtual environment and I have made sure all the proper PyQt5 packages are installed. After a bit more research I discovered that `libgssapi_krb5` is a Ubuntu system program. I have used `sudo apt -y install libgssapi-krb5-2` and `sudo apt -y install libgssapi-krb5-2:i386`. And the program is already installed on my system. I have tried to `purge` and `remove` my file but cannot because “This operation is not permitted because it will break the system.”

Here are some other sources I have found but their solutions have not worked for me:

- [ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory: HyperV Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61990391/importerror-libgl-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo)
- https://jobs.goyun.info/2020/01/how-to-fix-importerror-libgssapikrb5so2.html
- https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/libgssapi-krb5-2

I am not sure what else I can do fix this issue so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

one man's experience, but installing `rsyslog-gssapi` worked for me

I'm on void linux, linux version `5.15.24_1`

Comment: I use Fedora 36 and for me this did not work

Comment: `dev-python/gssapi` for those of us on Gentoo.